# Error while trying to run the app on the device

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment

I have received the developers phone from microsoft. I get an error while tryin to run my app which says "Ensure the target device screen is unlocked and that application is installed ".

1. I have registered and unlocked the phone.
2. Zune Software is running.
3. The screen is unlocked while tryin to run the app.
4. I have checked both 'Build' and 'Deploy' options of the Solution Property Pages.

Now what could be missing.??

Alfah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error I get is "Error 1 0x81030120". I am using the mango version windows phone.
Commenting out the following line in the WMAppManifest.xml will solve the issue.

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_INTEROPSERVICES"/>
```

Interopservices are not supported in mango version of Windows phone

Alfah